# oauth2 authentication c# code is not working

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to consume oauth2 api using auth code. In first step, i received auth by providing client id and secret, and now in 2nd step, i need access token using that auth code.
I tried below c# code

```
var client1 = new RestClient("https://ant.aliceblueonline.com/oauth2/token");
var request1 = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request1.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request1.AddParameter("code", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
request1.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
request1.AddParameter("redirect_uri", "https://ant.aliceblueonline.com/plugin/callback");
request1.AddParameter("client_id", "MM01418");
request1.AddParameter("client_secret", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
IRestResponse response = client1.Execute(request1);
```

In response, I get

> The OAuth 2.0 Client supports client authentication method "client_secret_basic", but method "client_secret_post" was requested. You must configure the OAuth 2.0 client's "token_endpoint_auth_method" value to accept "client_secret_post

Tried a lot but could not resolve it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all as you're working with C# I would like to recommend you to use [IdentityModel](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel) to interact with any OAuth2 authorization server or OpenId Connect Provider.

Let's start by the definition of a **Client**: A client is an application that is allowed to request acces tokens **on behalf** of the user. In your example your server runing the code you posted is the client.

To be able to use the `token` endpoint to request a new `access_token` a client must be able to prove its identity first, by providing a `client_id` and `client_secret` (like a user and password for clients).

There are **two** methods for providing this client credentials, from [IdentityServer4 documentation about secrets](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/secrets.html):

> **Authentication using a shared secret**
>
> You can either send the client id/secret combination as part of the POST body:
>
> ```
> POST /connect/token
> client_id=client1& client_secret=secret& ...
> ```
>
> ..or as a basic authentication header:
>
> ```
> POST /connect/token
> Authorization: Basic xxxxx
> ```

In this case, the error response is saying that just one of those methods is allowed, which is **Authentication header**

So instead of passing your client_id and client_secret along your request body:

```
request1.AddParameter("client_id", "MM01418");
request1.AddParameter("client_secret", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

you need to concat client_id and client_secret with a collon as separator like "MM01418:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" and apply base64 codification. Then add it to your request as header, of the form  `Authorization: Basic TU0wMTQxODp4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4eHh4`. You can do this in c# by using the following code:

```
var credentials = string.Format("{0}:{1}", clientId, clientSecret);
var headerValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials));

var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", headerValue);
```

or instead leave this low level details to a library like **IdentityModel** [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityModel/) [Docs](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/token.html) that implements the correct requests for you depending on the case.